# Recurring Event Filtering Using CAML queries

Tags: search, caml

I used following query to search between 2 dates ranges but it doesnt filter recurring instance of that day

```
  <Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-08-12T17:22:08Z</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-08-12T17:22:14Z</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

How can i show reccuring instances within this date ranges.if i put full date range than it shows that event, but single instance doesnt showup for a single day search